# Disable long press on smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, long-press

I have already had a usable code for disabling long press
but now I don't want to get element by ID. It's not possible for me to add Id for every particular items.
I want to make it works for every img in a Name Tag.
However, it's not working now. Please help.

Original working line:
    preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementById('theimage'));

Edited line:
    preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementByTagName('body img'));

entire code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function absorbEvent_(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }

    function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
      node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
    }

    function init() {
      preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementByTagName('body img'));
    }
  </script>
  <style>
    *:not(input):not(textarea) {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
        -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */

    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="init()" id="theimage" >
  <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/arthurboyd2010-hp.jpg" width="400">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misspelling the method name, and not passing the correct string. It's `getElementsByTagName` (note the `s` on elements), and you just pass the name of the tag not a css selector. You will also have to modify the function to loop over the result since it will be a nodelist

```
preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));

function preventLongPressMenu(nodes) {
  for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
     nodes[i].ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
     nodes[i].ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
     nodes[i].ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
     nodes[i].ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
  }
}
```

If the browser on the phone supports it you can also use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector#Browser_Compatibility)/[querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll#Browser_Compatibility), which allows you to use css selectors to select elements

```
preventLongPressMenu(document.querySelectorAll('body img'));

function preventLongPressMenu(nodes) {
  for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
     nodes[i].ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
     nodes[i].ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
     nodes[i].ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
     nodes[i].ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can also assign event handlers by JQuery, without using a `for` for each node:

```
function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
    node.on('touchstart', absorbEvent_);
    node.on('touchmove', absorbEvent_);
    node.on('touchend', absorbEvent_);
    node.on('touchcancel', absorbEvent_);
}
```

And so, instead of this:

```
function init() {
    preventLongPressMenu(document.getElementByTagName('body img'));
}
```

Do this:

```
function init() {
    preventLongPressMenu($('body img'));
}
```

## Just for using JQuery you have to implement it:

**From Google CDN:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**or from Microsoft CDN: "I prefer Google! :)"**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Better is to download the file from one of two CDNs and put it as local file, so the startup loading of your website's faster!

The choice is to you!

*To me it seems very much simplest than using DOM, I love JQuery! :)*